# Mysql access denied error when I try rake db:create

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I install mysql for RoR, and I get an access denied error. I've tried searching on the internet for how to go about fixing this ... but I have no clue on how to proceed right now.

Basically, I did this: 
`sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server libmysql-ruby1.8`

And I did get the password screen. I am sure I picked a password I know, and yet I am getting the following error when I try to run rake db:create: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using your hostname instead of localhost?

Comment: what is my hostname? my command line is this: parallels@ubuntu:~/Desktop$

Comment: your hostname is "ubuntu" based on your command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the instructions for resetting the root password from the official MySQL documentation:

Read this - [MySQL Root Password Reset Instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to connect to the database using

```
mysql -uroot -p -hlocalhost
```

or

```
mysql -uroot -p -h127.0.0.1
```

if your able to connect using the second but not the first, modify your database.yml file to include `Host: 127.0.0.1` and remove the line with `Socket`.

Comment: both give me "access denied". I just need a way to reset this password somehow ... that's what is so frustrating.